# Using bicond to get ID?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have this snippet of table called `joinTbl`:

```
PRODUCT_ID  PRODUCT_NAME    ORDER_ID     PRODUCT_ID      CUSTOMER_ID     SALESPERSON_ID      UNIT_PRICE 
   11          CAKE           10946          11               83              1                  31
   11          CAKE           10949          11               10              2                  31
   11          CAKE           11020          11               56              2                  31
   14          CHICKEN        11076          14               9               4                  23.25
   11          CAKE           11077          11               65              1                  31
   14          CHICKEN        11077          14               65              1                  23.25
```

In Pig Apache, I am trying to get the `ORDER_ID` if the order consist of both cake and chicken. The expected result is

```
11077
```

However I am facing issue trying to do a bicond to get this `ORDER_ID`. This is the syntax I used:

```
cakeChicken = FOREACH joinedTbl GENERATE ((PRODUCT_NAME == 'CAKE' AND PRODUCT_NAME == 'CHICKEN') ? ORDER_ID : 0) AS order_both;
```

The return from this is just `0` which is the else statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bincond is working correctly - as it's within `FOREACH`, it will check each row of data individually. Therefore, each row will only have one value for `PRODUCT_NAME`, so it cannot both be `'CAKE'` and `'CHICKEN'`.

Based on what you want to do, I would [use `GROUP BY`](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/basic.html#group) to group on `ORDER_ID` and then [filter](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/basic.html#filter) the `PRODUCT_NAME` bag to just those that contain `'CAKE'` and `'CHICKEN'` using a [nested foreach](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/basic.html#foreach). Finally, filter the data to "not empty" bags. Something like this:

```
groupedData = GROUP  joinTbl BY ORDER_ID;

/* Structure:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| groupedData | group | joinTbl: bag({PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, SALESPERSON_ID, UNIT_PRICE}) |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|             | 10946 | {(11, CAKE, 10946, 11, 83, 1, 31)}                                                                      |
|             | 11077 | {(11, CAKE, 11077, 11, 65, 1, 31), (14, CHICKEN,  11077, 14, 65, 1, 23.25)}                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

cakeChickenIds = FOREACH groupedData {
    cakes = FILTER joinTbl BY PRODUCT_NAME == 'CAKE';
    chickens = FILTER joinTbl BY PRODUCT_NAME == 'CHICKEN';
    GENERATE group AS ORDER_ID,
    cakes,
    chickens;
}

/* Structure:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| cakeChickenIds | ORDER_ID | cakes: bag({PRODUCT_NAME}) | chickens: bag({PRODUCT_NAME}) |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                | 10946    | {(CAKE)}                   | {()}                          |
|                | 11077    | {(CAKE)}                   | {(CHICKEN)}                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

-- Both cakes and chickens bags will not be empty if ordered both
cakeChickenOrders = FILTER cakeChickenIds BY NOT IsEmpty(cakes) AND NOT IsEmpty(chickens);
```

Comment: Hi Paul, could you explain on the initial start of the syntax - why `FOREACH (GROUP joinTbl BY ORDER_ID)`? I will appreciate if you can provide another set of syntax of the above but without using the curly brackets. I think if it is line by line, I will get it.

Comment: It’s not possible to solve without the curly brackets - a nested FOREACH is required. Will update the answer with links to the relevant documentation.